# Array binding to Kendo grid Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am trying to populate kendo grid from an array.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  private users:User[];
  constructor(private _sharedService:SharedService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.getJSON().subscribe((users)=>{
      console.log(users);
      this.users=users;
    }, (error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

users array will get data from a JSON file.

```
export class User {
    userId:String;
    userName:String;
    userAddress:String;
    userStatus:String
}
```

The html file look like..

```
<div class="container">
  <kendo-grid
  [kendoGridBinding]="users"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageable]="true"
  [sortable]="true"
  [filterable]="true"
  [groupable]="true"
  [height]="510">
  <kendo-grid-column field="Id" [width]="60"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="Name" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="Address" [width]="100"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="Status" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>

</div>
```

I just followed a tutorial.. But don't I need to unwind the array and set the columns like we do in a normal table?

The thing is it is just displaying the header and no data. What I have to do?

Comment: can i see what is there inside this.users?

Comment: export class User {
    userId:String;
    userName:String;
    userAddress:String;
    userStatus:String
} users is an array of User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing field attr as they are in users array.

```
  <kendo-grid-column field="userId" title="Id" [width]="60"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="userName" title="Name" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="userAddress" title="Address" [width]="100"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="userStatus" title="Status" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
```

You don't need to unwind the array manually as kendo grid's custom directives handles the mapping itself.

[Created Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-grid-select-all-dynamic-data-wsmcro?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @ShefZee glad it helped! feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the fields according to your users data,

```
<div class="container">
  <kendo-grid
  [kendoGridBinding]="users"
  [pageSize]="10"
  [pageable]="true"
  [sortable]="true"
  [filterable]="true"
  [groupable]="true"
  [height]="510">
<kendo-grid-column field="userId" title="Id" [width]="60"></kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="userName" title="Name" [width]="120"></kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="userAddress" title="Address" [width]="100"></kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="userStatus" title="Status" [width]="130"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, perfect :)

Comment: @ShefZee why you are removing answer, please mark abdul answer and upvote if my answer helped